# Revmob Unity : Banner ads not clickable

Tags: unity-game-engine, revmob

I am developing a game which required to show Revmob Banner ads.

I can successfully show banner ads, but can't not click on it. It's media id is into testing mode.

My code for it is below.

```
private RevMob rev mob;
void Awake() {
        revmob = RevMob.Start(REVMOB_APP_IDS, "RevMob");
    }
void Start() {
        revmob.CreateBanner(RevMob.Position.BOTTOM);
        revmob.ShowBanner(RevMob.Position.BOTTOM);
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Is this for Android or iOS?

Comment: I have tested for Android only.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line in the AndroidManifest.xml file within the activity tags for UnityPlayerNativeActivity

```
 <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
```

Example

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:largeHeap="true">
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />


  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />


</activity>
```